# How to detect if a symbol resolves to a (var containing a) macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

I'd like to be able to write something like

```
=> (macro? '->)
true
=>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macro vars have meta that marks it as a macro:

```
(defn macro? [s] (-> s resolve meta :macro boolean))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer.

Be aware that this will not work in ClojureScript where macros do not make it all the way into the runtime environment. This means for example that `(resolve 'if)` will return `nil`.